# Play two consecutive videos in ios app (objective-c)

Tags: objective-c, avfoundation, mpmediaplayercontroller

I have two video files with sound and I need to play them consecutive. I know I can use AVQueuePlayer to play them consecutive in a layer but I would rather use MPmediaPlayer because of its fetures - nice design, implemented stop, play, fullscreen mode bugless etc... Is it possible to play two consecutive videos (without gap) using default MPmediaPlayer?
Thank you. Have a nice day!

Comment: You really just want to know 'Yes' or 'No', and that will be it?

Comment: Thank you for your reaction. I need know  if there is a way and if so  how to perform it. I do not want full src code of course. Thank you for your time